Handing out DNS responses based on systemd-networkd's DHCP server
I can use something like
[Network]
DHCPServer=true

[Address]
Address=192.168.101.1/24

to make systemd-networkd act as a DHCP server.
With dnsmasq, dnsmasq would expose the current leases using DNS -- if a host foo connects, I could dig for foo against dnsmasq's DNS server and get back foo's assigned IP address. Does systemd-networkd and/or systemd-resolved support anything similar?
(I do see https://askubuntu.com/a/1488478/845995 for extracting this using DBus.)
